# How can I reverse the reversed order of numbers that are outputted in Dr java?

Tags: java

So I basically made a program that allows you to input a base 10 number and the computer shows that number converted into binary. The only problem is my numbers are in reverse order. For example:

```
     import java.util.Scanner;

          public class MathBinary


{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
      Scanner keys = new Scanner (System.in);

      int x;
      System.out.print("Type in a base 10");
      x = keys.nextInt();

     int mod = x%2;
     System.out.print(mod);
     int something = x/2;

     int mod1 = something%2;
     System.out.print(mod1);
     int something1 = something/2;

     int mod2 = something1%2;
     System.out.print(mod2);
     int something2 = something1/2;

     int mod3 = something2%2;
     System.out.print(mod3);
     int something3 = something2/2;


    }
}
```

Now if you typed in a base number such as 12, it outputs as "0011" when it should be "1100". How do I fix this?

Comment: The easiest fix for your code is remove all `println`, and do a `System.out.println("" + mod3 + mod2 + mod1 + mod);` at the end

Comment: But personally I would suggest you to rewrite your code in different ways, with 1. loops, 2. arrays, 3, bit-wise operators.  Your existing code can't even cope with an int > 16

Comment: (@AdrianShum) or if you want the correct result rather than practice programming just use `Integer.toString(x,2)`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I am aware there are better real-world solution for this.  However, given that is obviously some kind of exercise/homework, I'd rather suggest solution more appropriate in such aspect

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive call to output all binary values in correct order

```
public static void main (String[]args)
{
   Scanner keys = new Scanner (System.in);
   int x;
   System.out.print("Type in a base 10: ");
   x = keys.nextInt();
   reversePrint(x);
 } 

 private static void reversePrint(int x) {
   int mod = x%2;
   int something = x/2;
   if (something > 1)
     reversePrint(something);
   else
     System.out.print(something);
   System.out.print(mod);
 }
```